# Onclick in SVG element requires initial two clicks

Tags: javascript, svg, onclick

I have a little svg imagemap that has four quadrants.  When each quadrant is clicked on, it is supposed to change the opacity of a rectangle overlaying the grayscale base image.  When clicked again, the opacity goes back to 0.  It works great but it takes two clicks on each quadrant to get the thing going.

I have seen a lot of suggestions about using JQuery, but my understanding is that JQuery does not register onclicks in svg which is xml.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1200 808" >
    <image width="290" height="290" xlink:href="../includes-jar-code/_images/SquareTestGray.png">
    </image>
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/yellow">-->
        <rect onclick="top.notify(evt)" id="svgYellow" x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFF00" opacity="0" width="145" height="145" />       
        <text x="72" y="72" fill="red">Y</text>
    <!--</a>-->
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/pink">-->
        <rect onclick="top.notify(evt)" id="svgPink" x="0" y="146" fill="#FF00FF" opacity="0" width="145" height="145" />
        <text x="72" y="218" fill="red">P</text>
    <!--</a>-->
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/blue">-->
        <rect onclick="top.notify(evt)" id="svgBlue" x="146" y="0" fill="#0000FF" opacity="0" width="145" height="145" />
        <text x="218" y="72" fill="red">B</text>
    <!--</a>-->
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/green">-->
        <rect onclick="top.notify(evt)" id="svgGreen" x="146" y="146" fill="#008000" opacity="0" width="145" height="145" />
        <text x="218" y="218" fill="red">G</text>
    <!--</a>-->
</svg>

<script>

function notify(evt){

    if( document.getElementById(evt.target.id).style.opacity == "0" ) {
        document.getElementById(evt.target.id).style.opacity = ".25";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(evt.target.id).style.opacity = "0";
    }
}   

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Don't have a high enough reputation to post the background image.  It is a 290 x 290 px grayscale square divided evenly into 4 quadrants.

Your insights and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is happening? Is it going into the click? If it is, what is the value you are reading? `console.log(document.getElementById(evt.target.id).style.opacity)` My guess is the value is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

thats because you set the opacity attribute on the element, but you read the opacity style property which initialy is empty. you can either set the style on your elements instead of the attribute:

```js
function notify(evt){

    if( document.getElementById(evt.target.id).style.opacity == "0" ) {
        document.getElementById(evt.target.id).style.opacity = ".25";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(evt.target.id).style.opacity = "0";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1200 808" >
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="290" height="290" fill="royalblue" stroke="#53c"></rect>
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/yellow">-->
        <rect onclick="notify(evt)" id="svgYellow" x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFF00" style="opacity:0" width="145" height="145" />       
        <text x="72" y="72" fill="red">Y</text>
    <!--</a>-->
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/pink">-->
        <rect onclick="notify(evt)" id="svgPink" x="0" y="146" fill="#FF00FF" style="opacity:0"  width="145" height="145" />
        <text x="72" y="218" fill="red">P</text>
    <!--</a>-->
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/blue">-->
        <rect onclick="notify(evt)" id="svgBlue" x="146" y="0" fill="#0000FF" style="opacity:0"  width="145" height="145" />
        <text x="218" y="72" fill="red">B</text>
    <!--</a>-->
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/green">-->
        <rect onclick="notify(evt)" id="svgGreen" x="146" y="146" fill="#008000" style="opacity:0"  width="145" height="145" />
        <text x="218" y="218" fill="red">G</text>
    <!--</a>-->
</svg>



</body>
</html>
```

or you can set and read the attribute value from your script:

```js
function notify(evt){
    if(evt.target.getAttribute("opacity") == "0" ) {
        evt.target.setAttribute("opacity","0.25");
    } else {
        evt.target.setAttribute("opacity","0");
    }
}
```

```html
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlin<image width="290" height="290" xlink:href="../includes-jar-code/_images/SquareTestGray.png">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="290" height="290" fill="royalblue" stroke="#53c"></rect>
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/yellow">-->
        <rect onclick="notify(evt)" id="svgYellow" opacity="0" x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFF00"  width="145" height="145" />       
        <text x="72" y="72" fill="red">Y</text>
    <!--</a>-->
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/pink">-->
        <rect onclick="notify(evt)" id="svgPink" x="0" y="146" fill="#FF00FF" opacity="0" width="145" height="145" />
        <text x="72" y="218" fill="red">P</text>
    <!--</a>-->
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/blue">-->
        <rect onclick="notify(evt)" id="svgBlue" x="146" y="0" fill="#0000FF" opacity="0" width="145" height="145" />
        <text x="218" y="72" fill="red">B</text>
    <!--</a>-->
    <!--<a xlink:href="//jarea.com/green">-->
        <rect onclick="notify(evt)" id="svgGreen" x="146" y="146" fill="#008000" opacity="0" width="145" height="145" />
        <text x="218" y="218" fill="red">G</text>
    <!--</a>-->
</svg>
```

Comment: I would like to accept your answer Holger however I do not have sufficient reputation to do so.  Actually, I did accept the answer but it will not become public until my reputation rises to an adequate level.